# What does the registry value for the outlook(2003) msgfile extension stand for?

Tags: outlook, registry, vsto

If you want to open an msg Email file with the extension .msg, Outlook 2003 will be started with some parameters. Therefore you can find the following registry keys:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\msgfile\shell\Open\command\(standard)
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\msgfile\shell\Open\command\command
```

The first one points to the "outlook.exe" with the parameter /f "%1". This starts Outlook with the information to open the mail.
But the "command" key has the following value:

```
%]gAVn-}f(ZXfeAR6.jiOUTLOOKFiles>ir@X7cr$%@u$}&V7{4p' /f "%1"
```

Can anybody tell me what exactly this is good for?

I'm writing an vsto Outlook Addin for which I need to modify these keys. In case I modify the "standard" key, Outlook will be started normaly without using my alteration of the key. If I also modify the "command" key Outlook does not even start anymore.

Only if I delete the "command" key everything works fine as expected. But without knowing what the key is good for, this cannot be a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this "command" value is a so-called "Darwin Descriptor" generated by Windows Installer to automatically repair a broken installation.

See http://www.symantec.com/community/tip/4999/darwin-descriptor or google for "MSI darwin descriptor".

Comment: Link is broken. MSDN has a page with some information on this topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302344.aspx